# Makefile conditional variable assignment

Tags: makefile

I wish to make the following target:

```
ifeq ("$(VARENV1)", "true")
    VARENV3=$(VARENV2)
endif

dummy:
    echo $(VARENV3)
```

I am then calling my makefile with

```
VARENV1=true VARENV2=test make dummy
```

expecting to get a display of "test".

But this fail as `VARENV3` is empty.

However, if I use the following makefile:

```
ANYVARNAME=ANYVALUE
ifeq ("$(VARENV1)", "true")
    VARENV3=$(VARENV2)
endif

dummy:
    echo $(VARENV3)
```

Purpose is to override VARENV3 with VARENV2 in some condition.

Then I will correctly display "test".

I am bit confused at why, any clue?

Comment: There must be something about your makefile that's different than this example: when I run your example exactly as you suggest, it works as expected (shows `echo test`).  Whatever that difference is, is what is causing your problem.

Comment: I have two things to suggest: first, you don't need quotes in your `ifeq`.  Make doesn't care about quoting... you're just comparing the quote characters they don't mean anything special to make.  Since you have them on both sides of the equality they match, so it doesn't matter, but you don't need them.

Comment: Second, since you suggest that adding a new variable assignment "fixes" the problem, my suspicion is that (1) the difference between your failing version and the version you posted here is that in the failing version there's some other rule before the `ifeq`, and (2) you have indented the `VARENV3 = $(VARENV2)` with a TAB character.  That would mean that the assignment is considered to be part of the previous recipe.  By adding the assignment (not indented with TAB) you have "ended" the previous rule.

Comment: Simple rule of makefiles: _always_ indent every recipe line with TAB and _never_ indent any line that is not a recipe line with TAB.

Comment: You were correct, this was because I had a previous rule messing up with my var assignment.
Thanks a lot !